# envoyer des lettres (à) n'importe où dans le monde

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

Is Preposition *à* to be put in front of *n'importe où*? Or is it optional?

- On peut envoyer des lettres (à) n'importe où dans le monde.

Answer (score 1):

*N'importe où* cannot<sup>1</sup> be preceded by *à* in that expression (juste like *où* is unlikely to be) so that must be:

> On peut envoyer des lettres n'importe où dans le monde.

which is ambiguous. To make clear what you want to say, it can be used either with *de*:

> On peut envoyer des lettres **de** n'importe où dans le monde.

which means **from** anywhere in the world, or, to mean *to anywhere*, you might use:

> On peut envoyer des lettres **à destination de** n'importe où dans le monde.

Note that unlike *où*, *qui* can be preceded by either *à* or *de*, so both forms can be used:

> *On peut envoyer des lettres **à** n'importe qui*.
>
> *On peu recevoir des lettres **de** n'importe qui*.

<sup>1</sup><sub>There are however rare cases where it is possible, especially when used in the expression "from xxx to anywhere" (*de xxx à n'importe où*) as aCOSwt commented.</sub>

Comment: J'ai mis +1 car, oui, ici, tu as raison. Maintenant il convient de ne pas généraliser (*N'importe où cannot be preceded by à*) De fait *à n'importe où* se trouve chez de *bons auteurs* (Jean Claude Piguet), de moins bons aussi... , certaines revues des années 70 et... le fait qu'avec l'avion maintenant... tu sais... *on peut bien aller de n'importe où **à n'importe où***